# Discord.js | Trouble to find user connect and disconnect event

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a statistic feature in my bot, and I want it to refresh as many  times as necessary. 
So I have

```
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
   (...)
});
```

and

```
bot.on("guildMemberRemove", (member) => {
   (...)
});
```

to refresh this :
[channel with the member count, and online count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s0O8.png)

I've seen somes events like "disconnect" but don't know if it's the good event, and can't figure out how to use it if it's right.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client's [`presenceUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate) event will be emitted whenever a guild member's status changes. For example, if a user goes from offline to online, or their game changes from one to another.

Consider this listener...

```js
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  if (oldMember.presence.status !== newMember.presence.status) {
  // The user's status changed
    if (oldMember.presence.status === 'offline' || newMember.presence.status === 'offline') {
    // The user's status changed from or to offline
      const online = newMember.guild.members.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size;
      // Use the online count here.
  }
});
```